# Is AJAX a Rest api

Tags: ajax, rest

Recently I have been working on Ajax. So according to me AJAX displays content in HTML using XML. But now does this mean it is a Rest api.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

AJAX is a set of (typically) client-sided web development techniques, while REST is an architecture style for sending and handling HTTP requests.
So you can use AJAX to send RESTful requests.
A REST API is typically not implemented using AJAX, but can be accessed by an AJAX client.

There is plenty of information on both AJAX and REST (API) on the Internet. It should be easy to find.

Comment: Thanks A lot. No I understand. Defintely will look mor einto it. Thanks a lot @InMyHumbleOpinion.

Comment: I think confusion often comes from the 'X' in AJAX which would seem to require using XML, whereas REST requests typically return JSON (in addition to having a particular URL pattern). But you can basically replace the X in AJAX with 'any structured text data' that you can parse and inject into your loaded document - you can use JSON. So if you make an asynchronous request the AJAX way, but the request is a REST call exchanging JSON, you're using REST and AJAX together - just not 'XML'. These days one can treat the X in AJAX like an asterisk.

Answer (score 4):

Using REST we can do operations (PUT,POST,GET,HEAD) but by using AJAX we can only retrieve data from server side , AJAX can be a part of REST but REST can never be AJAX
http://rest.elkstein.org/2008/02/ajax-and-rest.html

Comment: then what is AJAX get or post request that we can perform? @sai ram

Comment: Wang here you go - https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp and https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp

Comment: You can do more than GET (retrieval) requests with AJAX